# Get running no series on basis of one column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like

```
SELECT str AS company, item#, Qty
FROM temp_on_hand
WHERE qty > 2
ORDER BY Item# ASC
```

output of that query is -

```
company  item#  Qty 
1         746   3 
5        9526   1
1       14096   1
2       14096   2
3       14095   2
```

I want to generate new item#( with addition of '-0001' to current item#) on basis of Qty column i.e.  if Qty column has value 3 for company 1 than query should return three rows like -

```
company    NewItem#   Item#  Qty
  1       746-00001    746    3
  1       746-00002    746    3
  1       746-00003    746    3
  5      9526-00001   9526    1
  1     14096-00001  14096    1
  2     14096-00002  14096    2  
  2     14096-00003  14096    2
  3     14095-00001  14095    3
  3     14095-00002  14095    3
  3     14095-00003  14095    3
```

. . . . . . .

Table structure like that

```
CREATE TABLE temp_on_hand(str INT, item# INT,Qty INT)

INSERT INTO temp_on_hand VALUES (1,   746,    3)
INSERT INTO temp_on_hand VALUES (5,  9526,    1)
INSERT INTO temp_on_hand VALUES (1, 14096,    1)
INSERT INTO temp_on_hand VALUES (2, 14096,    2)
INSERT INTO temp_on_hand VALUES (3, 14095,    2)

ALTER TABLE temp_on_hand ADD new_item# VARCHAR)
```

similarly for upcoming values.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What RDBMS are you *really* using?

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: @stickybit, i have edited question and add create/insert statement.

Comment: @Larnu, i m using SSMS 2014.

Comment: SSMS isn't a DBMS but just a client. SQL Server is a DBMS though.

Comment: What version of SSMS you're using doesn't *really* help us. SSMS 2014 supports SQL Server 2005-2014. Though, unless you're using SQL Server 2005 (which i really hope you're not) Why haven't you updated to SSMS 18?

Comment: Your results show `qty = 1` but that violates the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive CTE is a simple method:

```
WITH cte as (
      SELECT str AS company, item#, Qty, 1 as n
      FROM temp_on_hand
      WHERE qty > 2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT company, item#, Qty, n + 1
      FROM cte
      WHERE n < Qty
     )
SELECT str, item# + format(n, '0000') as newitem#, item#, qty
FROM cte;
```

Note that if `qty` exceeds 100, you will also need `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

EDIT:

If you want the numbering within a company, you can use window functions and a cumulative sum:

```
WITH cte as (
      SELECT str AS company, item#, Qty, 1 as n,
             SUM(qty) OVER (PARTITION BY str ORDER BY item#) - qty as start_qty
      FROM temp_on_hand
      WHERE qty > 2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT company, item#, Qty, n + 1, start_qty
      FROM cte
      WHERE n < Qty
     )
SELECT str,
       item# + format(n + start_qty, '0000') as newitem#, item#, qty
FROM cte;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, if it is possible than can we get running no without breaking on str i.e. Company. Right now whenever company change it again start from -00001. We don't want to restart from 1 again, we want it will be next upcoming no, doesn't matter company change or not.

Comment: if possible could you please modified according it.

Answer (score 2):

**You can join to a Numbers table.**

You can use a real one, but I will use [Itzik Ben-Gan's on-the-fly tally table](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1) (it's actually better as an inline Table-valued Function).

**EDIT:** According to your comments, you don't actually need the numbering from `Nums`, you want a fresh overall numbering. So you can just select from `L1`

```sql
WITH
    L0 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c 
            FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS D(c) ),
    L1 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 A, L0 B ),  -- add more cross joins for more rows
SELECT
    t.str AS company,
    t.item# + FORMAT(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.item# ASC), '-0000') NewItem#,
    t.item#,
    t.Qty
FROM temp_on_hand t
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP (t.Qty) c
    FROM L1
) n
WHERE t.qty > 2
ORDER BY t.Item#, n.rownum ASC;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=930920c5d0eed04b7373555215986365)

Comment: Why not just plug L1 into the query?

Comment: Dunno, feels neater. Perf will be the same either way

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, We want to get running no without breaking on str i.e. Company. Right now whenever company change it again start from -00001. We don't want to restart from 1 again, we want it will be next upcoming no, doesn't matter company change or not.

Comment: if possible could you please modified according that.

Comment: OK done, but that does limit you to 100k possible numbers

Answer (score 2):

The key to good performance using a numbers table based approach is to make sure the row expansion is constrained by a row goal, i.e. `SELECT TOP(n)`, without a row goal the full cartesian product is used.  Also, the FORMAT function is known to be slow.
You could try something like this

[EDIT]: The sequence assigned to the NewItem# does not reset for each (startdate, enddate) pair.

```
drop TABLE if exists #temp_on_hand;
go
CREATE TABLE #temp_on_hand(str INT, item# INT,Qty INT)

INSERT INTO #temp_on_hand VALUES
(1,   746,    3),
 (5,  9526,    1),
 (1, 14096,    1),
 (2, 14096,    2),
 (3, 14095,    3);

with
l as (select 1 n from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) as v(n))
select *, concat_ws('-', item#, 
       right('00000'+cast(row_number() over (order by (select null)) as varchar(5)), 5)) NewItem#
from #temp_on_hand toh
     cross apply (select top (toh.Qty) 1 n
                  from l l1, l l2,l l3, l l4) tally;
```

```
str item#   Qty n   NewItem#
1   746     3   1   746-00001
1   746     3   1   746-00002
1   746     3   1   746-00003
5   9526    1   1   9526-00004
1   14096   1   1   14096-00005
2   14096   2   1   14096-00006
2   14096   2   1   14096-00007
3   14095   3   1   14095-00008
3   14095   3   1   14095-00009
3   14095   3   1   14095-00010
```